# Matlab: creating a bigger array using a smaller array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have two giant array which looks like:

```
A = [11, 11, 12, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ];
B = [ 12, 4; 3, 11; 11, 1; 4, 13 ];
```

I want to create an array which takes values from B and column 1 from A to look like:

```
C = [ 11, 1; 11, 1; 12, 4; 3, 11; 3, 11; 4, 13; 4, 13; 4, 13 ];
```

I don't want to use for or any other kind of loop to optimize the process.

Sorry for being terse.

I will search each element from column 1 of A in column 1 of B and pick the corresponding column 2 elements from B and create a new array with column 1 elements of A and discovered column 2 elements from B.

Comment: this needs EVEN MORE explaining!

Comment: Done.  Check my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing in this problem is using `A` and searching the first column of `B` to see if there's a match.  Once there's a match, extract out the row that corresponds to this matched location in `B`.  Repeat this for the rest of the values in `A`.

Assuming that all values of `A` can be found in `B` and that the first column of `B` is **distinct** and that there are no duplicates, you can a `unique` call and `sortrows` call.  The `unique` call is on `A` so that you can assign each value in `A` to be a unique label in sorted order.  You would then use these labels to index into the sorted version of `B` to get your desired result:

```
[~,~,id] = unique(A);
Bs = sortrows(B);
C = Bs(id,:);
```

We get for `C`:

```
C =

    11     1
    11     1
    12     4
     3    11
     3    11
     4    13
     4    13
     4    13
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't require an intermediate variable. On the other hand, it needs to sort a larger matrix

Comment: @LuisMendo - Correct!  I suspect that your answer will be more efficient in the long run.

Comment: Sorry the answer was great but my problem was not well formulated I suppose. I have modified my problem statement.

Comment: @user1243255 you're very welcome.  Sorry for being terse with you earlier... just that you new edit didn't make any sense until you corrected yourself.

Answer (score 3):

*Thanks to @rayryeng for clarifying the question to me*.

- Assuming each element from `A` is present in column 1 of `B`:

  ```
  [~, ind] = max(bsxfun(@eq, A(:).', B(:,1)), [], 1);
  C = B(ind,:);
  ```
- If that assumption doesn't necessarily hold:

  ```
  [val, ind] = max(bsxfun(@eq, A(:).', B(:,1)), [], 1);
  C = B(ind(val),:);
  ```

  So for example `A = [11, 20, 12, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ];` would produce

  ```
  C =
      11     1
      12     4
       3    11
       3    11
       4    13
       4    13
       4    13
  ```

Comment: Sorry the answer was great but my problem was not well formulated I suppose. I have modified my problem statement.